# How to disable an Excel context menu item

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code which is meant to disable certain Excel context menu items when the Worksheet protection is OFF. I had it working for a couple of runs now it throws an error, "Runtime error 424, Object required". The variable "ctrl" is nothing, so I assume that is the issue. I checked the Object browser and I think that the code is correct, and it didn't have an error a couple of times it was run. However when I closed the Workbook and reopened it I got the error message.

```
Public Sub Set_Menus(Optional CloseUp As Boolean = False)
' Set the visibility of some context menu items to prevent issues
' Use the app BuiltInControlsScanner.exe for ids (in /etc)
' Sheet1.Range("T16") saves the value of the workbook protected or not

Dim ctrl As Office.CommandBarControl
Dim arrIdx(13) As Long
Dim idx As Variant

    ' Assign values to each element of the array - arrIdx, this can be added to as needed ;)
    arrIdx(0) = 292       ' Cell Delete
    arrIdx(1) = 293       ' Row Delete
    arrIdx(2) = 294       ' Column Delete
    arrIdx(3) = 3181      ' Cell Insert
    arrIdx(4) = 3183      ' Row & Column Insert
    arrIdx(5) = 3125      ' Clear Contents
    arrIdx(6) = 31402     ' Cell Filter
    arrIdx(7) = 31435     ' Cell Sort
    arrIdx(8) = 541       ' Row Height
    arrIdx(9) = 542       ' Column Height
    arrIdx(10) = 883      ' Row Hide
    arrIdx(11) = 884      ' Row Unhide
    arrIdx(12) = 886      ' Column Hide
    arrIdx(13) = 887      ' Column Unhide

    If Sheet1.Range("T16").value = True Or CloseUp = True Then
    ' If the workbook is protected or we want to close it, set them back to Visible...
        For Each idx In arrIdx
            For Each ctrl In Application.CommandBars.FindControls(ID:=idx)
                ctrl.Enabled = True
            Next ctrl
        Next idx

    Else ' Hide the menu items
        For Each idx In arrIdx
            For Each ctrl In Application.CommandBars.FindControls(ID:=idx)
                ctrl.Enabled = False
            Next ctrl
        Next idx
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: apart from no null handling, you real issue is that 3181 and 3183 are not available in Excel -2016. To disable insert, use 295, 945 and 27690

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if `FindControls` returns nothing.

Note that I introduced a variable `ShowItems` so you don't need to repeat your loop code twice.

```
Public Sub Set_Menus(Optional CloseUp As Boolean = False)
' Set the visibility of some context menu items to prevent issues
' Use the app BuiltInControlsScanner.exe for ids (in /etc)
' Sheet1.Range("T16") saves the value of the workbook protected or not

Dim ctrl As Office.CommandBarControl
Dim arrIdx(13) As Long
Dim idx As Variant
Dim FoundControls As CommandBarControls

    ' Assign values to each element of the array - arrIdx, this can be added to as needed ;)
    arrIdx(0) = 292       ' Cell Delete
    arrIdx(1) = 293       ' Row Delete
    arrIdx(2) = 294       ' Column Delete
    arrIdx(3) = 3181      ' Cell Insert
    arrIdx(4) = 3183      ' Row & Column Insert
    arrIdx(5) = 3125      ' Clear Contents
    arrIdx(6) = 31402     ' Cell Filter
    arrIdx(7) = 31435     ' Cell Sort
    arrIdx(8) = 541       ' Row Height
    arrIdx(9) = 542       ' Column Height
    arrIdx(10) = 883      ' Row Hide
    arrIdx(11) = 884      ' Row Unhide
    arrIdx(12) = 886      ' Column Hide
    arrIdx(13) = 887      ' Column Unhide

    Dim ShowItems As Boolean
    If Sheet1.Range("T16").Value = True Or CloseUp = True Then
        ShowItems = True
    Else ' Hide the menu items
        ShowItems = False
    End If

    ' If the workbook is protected or we want to close it, set them back to Visible...
    For Each idx In arrIdx
        Set FoundControls = Application.CommandBars.FindControls(ID:=idx)
        If Not FoundControls Is Nothing Then 'if no CommandBarControls were found skip the following
            For Each ctrl In FoundControls
                ctrl.Enabled = ShowItems
            Next ctrl
        End If
    Next idx
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sometimes the simple solution escapes me...At first I was resistant to adding the new var "ShowItems" because I don't mind the repetitive loops (I can cut and Paste). However I can see now that it makes the code more easily read and therefore maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

When I ran the Recommended code I got a "Invalid use of property" compile error. The error suggested that the new var "FoundControls" was the issue. So I changed the code as shown in the following and it seems to work just fine...it adds the SET command to the variable "FoundControls" assignment and avoids the error. Thank you again...

```
' If the workbook is protected or we want to close it, set them back to Visible...
For Each idx In arrIdx
    Set mnuControls = Application.CommandBars.FindControls(ID:=idx)
    If Not mnuControls Is Nothing Then 'if no CommandBarControls were found skip the following
        For Each ctrl In mnuControls
            ctrl.Enabled = ShowItems
        Next ctrl
    End If
Next idx
```

Comment: Of course it needs a `Set` because it is an object. Couldn't test the code so I missed that. Fixed my answer.